# Ubuntu 12.04 Sftp fails while ssh succeeds

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I did look up stackoverflow for the same issue, but could not figure out what was not working on my system.

{**EDIT**} Not sure about why this question is being down voted. Please do comment below, so we know what not to ask here.

Problem statement: ssh connection is successful. Sftp closes after authentication.

The following is what I find int the DEBUG3 level sshd logs:

```
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: subsystem request for sftp by user sftpuser
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: subsystem: exec() /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -p /opt/bbee/lib/libbbee_sftp_stats.so.0.0.0
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9713]: debug3: Copy environment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9713]: debug3: Copy environment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/bbee/thirdparty/lib/5.x:/opt/bbee/lib:/opt/bbee/thirdparty/lib:/opt/bbee/thirdparty/lib/openhpi
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9713]: debug3: Copy environment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9713]: debug3: Copy environment: LANGUAGE=en_US:
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: session_by_pid: pid 9713
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 9713
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: request exit-signal confirm 0
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: write failed
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: close_write
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: send eow
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: output open -> closed
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 9 len 0
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: read failed
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: close_read
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: read 0 from efd 11
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: closing read-efd 11
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: send eof
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: send close
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: notify_done: reading
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: Received disconnect from 192.168.2.17: 11: disconnected by user
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug1: do_cleanup
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9712]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9310]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9310]: debug1: do_cleanup
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9310]: debug1: PAM: cleanup
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9310]: debug1: PAM: closing session
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 sshd[9310]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user sftpuser
```

I find the following in kern.log

```
Nov 15 05:52:22 cz1 kernel: [97296.394274] sftp-server[65421]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f26e15c6b94 sp 00007fffaa9d0470 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7f26e1558000+1b4000]
Nov 15 05:56:56 cz1 kernel: [97569.802937] sftp-server[9713]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f8d75558b94 sp 00007fff64043130 error 4 in libc-2.15.so[7f8d754ea000+1b4000]
```

The sftp is failing for sftpuser only NOT for another user I have created.

The `/etc/passwd` for sftpuser is:

```
sftpuser:x:1004:1004::/home/sftpuser:/bin/bash
```

I also see that I have a home directory for `sftpuser`

```
ls -ltar /home/sftpuser/
total 48
-rw-r--r--  1 sftpuser sftpuser   220 Mar 28  2013 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 sftpuser sftpuser  3629 Jun  6 21:47 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 26 root     root      4096 Jun  7 02:00 ..
drwx------  2 sftpuser sftpuser  4096 Nov 11 07:51 .cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 sftpuser sftpuser 11723 Nov 15 02:44 sftpfail
-rw-r--r--  1 sftpuser sftpuser   675 Nov 15 04:21 .profile
-rw-------  1 sftpuser sftpuser  1973 Nov 15 04:56 .viminfo
drwx------  2 sftpuser sftpuser  4096 Nov 15 04:56 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  4 sftpuser sftpuser  4096 Nov 15 04:56 .
-rw-------  1 sftpuser sftpuser   701 Nov 15 04:56 .bash_history
```

My sshd configuration looks like:

```
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -p /opt/bbee/lib/libbbee_sftp_stats.so.0.0.0
```

sftp-server does a dlopen on libbbee_sftp_stats.so.0.0.0. We have all this library in the right path. I see the LD_LIBRARY_PATH being exported for sshd daemon.

Also I do not find any echo in `/home/sftpuser/.profile, .bashrc` etc

NOTE: The same configuration works for another user.

What am I missing?

{**EDIT**}

I have modified sftp-server code to get a callback .

```
*(void **) (&plugin_process) = dlsym(plugin, "sftp_plugin_process");
      if ((plugin_err = dlerror()) != NULL) {
        fatal("Failed to find \"sftp_plugin_process\" function in \"%s\": \"%s\"",
            optarg, plugin_err);
      }
```

And similarly, while doing open() I made some changes to get my callback invoked:

In sftp-server code to open:

```
static void
process_open(void)
{
    u_int32_t id, pflags;
    Attrib *a;
    char *name;
    int handle, fd, flags, mode, status = SSH2_FX_FAILURE;

    id = get_int();
    name = get_string(NULL);
    pflags = get_int();     /* portable flags */
    debug3("request %u: open flags %d", id, pflags);
    a = get_attrib();
    flags = flags_from_portable(pflags);
    mode = (a->flags & SSH2_FILEXFER_ATTR_PERMISSIONS) ? a->perm : 0666;
    logit("open \"%s\" flags %s mode 0%o",
        name, string_from_portable(pflags), mode);
    if (readonly &&
        ((flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_WRONLY || (flags & O_ACCMODE) == O_RDWR))
        status = SSH2_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED;
    else {
        fd = open(name, flags, mode);
        if (fd < 0) {
            status = errno_to_portable(errno);
        } else {
            handle = handle_new(HANDLE_FILE, name, fd, NULL);
            if (handle < 0) {
                close(fd);
            } else {
                send_handle(id, handle);
                status = SSH2_FX_OK;
            }
        }
    }
    if (status != SSH2_FX_OK) {
        send_status(id, status);
  } 
  if (plugin != NULL) {  ///////////////////////////////// ADDED CODE HERE TO GET A CALLBACK found in libbee_sftp_stats.so.0.0.0
    plugin_process(cookie, client_addr, name, SSH2_FXP_OPEN);
  } ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    xfree(name);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -p /opt/bbee/lib/libbbee_sftp_stats.so.0.0.0` will do?

Comment: @Jakuje : I have updated the details.